# HSQLDB Stored Procedure Error: attempt to assign to non-updatable column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax-error, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB 2.3.2 and am getting a bizarre error when trying to create a stored procedure.

My `addresses` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses (
    address_id                  INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    address_line_1              NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    address_line_2              NVARCHAR(500),
    address_city                NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    address_postal_code         NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT uc_addresses UNIQUE (address_line_1, address_city)
)
```

An insert to populate it:

```
INSERT INTO addresses (
    address_line_1,
    address_city,
    address_postal_code
) VALUES (
    '123 Test Blvd.', 'Testville', '11111'
)
```

And my proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_address_by_id(
        IN address_id INTEGER,
        OUT address_id  INTEGER,
        OUT address_line_1 NVARCHAR(500),
        OUT address_line_2 NVARCHAR(500),
        OUT address_city NVARCHAR(100),
        OUT address_postal_code NVARCHAR(25))
    READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN ATOMIC
        SELECT
            a.address_id,
            a.address_line_1,
            a.address_line_2,
            a.address_city,
            a.address_postal_code
        INTO
            address_id,
            address_line_1,
            address_line_2,
            address_city,
            address_postal_code
        FROM
            addresses a 
        WHERE
            a.address_id = address_id;
    END
```

When I run this I get:

```
Error: attempt to assign to non-updatable column
SQLState:  0U000
ErrorCode: -2500
```

Questions:

1. What is wrong with my proc (what is producing this error)?
2. I'm actually looking for a `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS`-type declaration, so I can run this script over and over again and the procedure will only get created one time if it doesn't already exist. Will this happen or do I need to change the syntax to accomplish `IF NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Why in your procedure you called IN parameter the same as OUT parameter (address_id)?

Comment: Try changing name of your IN parameter to unical one. Or try to change these two lines into 'INOUT address_id  INTEGER'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the syntax below, according to the hsqldb documentation
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_assignment

> The SET statement is used for assignment. It can be used flexibly with
>   rows or single values.

Also change the `address_id` parameter to type `INOUT` and remove the duplicate `address_id` parameter lines.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_address_by_id(
    INOUT address_id INTEGER,
    OUT address_line_1 NVARCHAR(500),
    OUT address_line_2 NVARCHAR(500),
    OUT address_city NVARCHAR(100),
    OUT address_postal_code NVARCHAR(25))
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
    SET (address_id,
        address_line_1,
        address_line_2,
        address_city,
        address_postal_code)
    = 
    (
    SELECT
        a.address_id,
        a.address_line_1,
        a.address_line_2,
        a.address_city,
        a.address_postal_code
    FROM
        addresses a 
    WHERE
        a.address_id = address_id
    );
END
```

You can try adding this as the first statement in your script if you want to drop the procedure if it already exists, so that you can re-run the script many times. You can search the [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html) for `<specific routine designator>` for more info.

```
DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE sp_get_address_by_id IF EXISTS;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your procedure you have two parameters with the same name:

```
IN address_id INTEGER,
OUT address_id  INTEGER,
```

It may cause a problem when you refer to `address_id` in the body of procedure.
You should rather use:

```
INOUT address_id  INTEGER,
```

instead of these two lines.

Answering your second question:
Why do you want to run this script over and over again without rebuilding the procedure? Running this script again has sense when something has changed in it.

- If you don't plan to change this procedure but you want to change other things in your script then maybe you should simply move this procedure to other script and run it only once
- If you plan to change the body of procedure then it should be rebuilded every time. So you should use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`

Answer (score 0):

For followers, the same error message is thrown if you do this:

```
 PreparedStatement selectStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
 ResultSet rs = selectStmt.executeQuery()) {
 rs.next();
 rs.updateLong("column", value); // boom
```

one fix is to use this style:

```
 PreparedStatement selectStmt = 
    conn.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```